# Using a function inside a class

Tags: python, list, class, object, methods

I am trying to make a receipt program by making a list of ware objects. I do this by making a class and function like:

```
class ware(object):

    def __init__(self, code, name, price, quantity):
        self.code= code
        self.name = name
        self.price = price    
        self.quantity= quantity

    def code (self):
        return self.code

def my_wares():
    wares_from_file= open("wares.txt", "r")
    list_of_wares= []
    for line in wares_from file:
        every_ware1= line
        every_ware2= varje_vara1.split("/")
        wares= ware(every_ware2[0],every_ware2[1], every_ware2[2], every_ware2[3])
        list_of_wares.append(varorna)

    list_of_wares.sort()
    return(list_of_wares)
```

After i have made my list of object, i call my function in the main function by:

```
def main():
    all_wares = my_wares()
```

Now i need to use this list of ware objects inside another class method, i tried by doing:

```
class receipt_part(ware):
    def __init__(self, kod, namn, pris, butik_antal):
        ware.__init__(self, code, name, price, quantity)
        self.price_toal= 0
        self.customer_quantity= 0

    def shop_ware(kod):
        wares_quantity= input("how many wares does the customer wants?")
        self.name= all_wares[1]
        self.price= all_wares[2] 
        peice_total+= all_wares[3]*wares_quantity
        customer_quantity+= int(wares_quantity)
        quantity= int(all_wares[4]) - int(wares_quantity)
        __str__()
```

But it says that all_wares is not defined, although I used it in my main function, why is that?

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: Take a look at collections.namedtuple(), which is a uniform way to define "class ware" (which should be class Ware according to PEP 8).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a variable in one function and use it in another function even if the first function is called `main`. You need to pass the variable to the second function explicitly.

Comment: or at the top of main add `global my_global_var`

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's a bad idea. Sure, you have even some other methods to do that but they are usually not the best ones.

Comment: I didn't say it was a great Idea ... but it looks like he wanted a global variable, and to be honest there are times where globals make sense despite the general bad-idea-ness of them (granted legitimate cases are few and far between)

Comment: How do i pass the second variable in to the second function explicitly? How do i transfer the list obtained through def my_wares() to the method shop_wares?

Comment: @Bardolf in your case you probably need to rethink your class structure